# Specific structure array string gets skipped when printed

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, structure

I am creating a program that takes data from a text file and stores it into a structure array. I used `strcpy` to do that for all string values that I had to store. Every line in this file is a different parameter.

Below is an example of how I accomplished that; I am aware that there are certainly much better ways of going about this task however I am still very much a beginner in C and this is all I could muster.

*Input data sample:*

```
A-0123-21
John
Doe
1 | 4 | 19 | 5 | 62 | 0 | 13 | 5 | 1 | 61 |
----------------------------------------------
```

```c
typedef struct student
{
    char index[10];
    char name[23];
    char surname[23];
    int scores[11];
}students;

typedef struct raw
{
    char score[70];
    char divider[70];
}data;


students st[120];
data rw[120];

void init_load()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char line[100];
    if((fp=fopen("students.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bool s1=false,s2=false,s3=false,s4=false,s5=false;

    int id=0;
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {

        if (s5 == true)
        {
            s1=false; s2=false; s3=false; s4=false; s5=false;
            strcpy(((st+id)->index), line);
            s1=true;
            id++;

        }else if (s4 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((rw+id)->divider), line);
            s5=true;
        }else if (s3 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((rw+id)->score), line);
            s4=true;
        }else if(s2 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((st+id)->surname), line);
            s3=true;
        }else if(s1 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((st+id)->name), line);
            s2=true;
        }else
        {
            strcpy(((st+id)->index), line);
            s1=true;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
```

This code seemingly works fine here. If I add `printf("%s", (st+id)->name);` to this loop it will print the names with no issues or extra characters.

However, when I call the same `printf` in a print function it skips the string as if it had an escape sequence. For example:

```c
void print_students()
{
    for(int i=0;i<120;i++)
    {
        printf("%s", (st+i)->index);
        printf("%s", (st+i)->name);
        printf("%s", (st+i)->surname);
    }
}
```

The `name` string gets skipped, but the other ones print out just fine even though I applied the same logic to all of them. Here is what happens after this code is run:

```
I-0482-20
Smith
I-0495-20
Simonian
I-0494-20
Sullivan
```

I am sorry for any glaring mistakes but as I've stated earlier I am still learning.

Comment: The biggest glaring mistake in the code above is what is *not* in the code above: a proper [mcve] with which we, via copy/paste/compile/run, can reproduce the problem you state you're facing. The statements "while I am in this function" and "when I call the same printf elsewhere" *beg* for clarification which is easily provided with a proper reproduction.

Comment: Code style guidelines (and hence tangential to your problem) — You have: `strcpy(((st+id)->name), line);` — you could/should use `strcpy(st[id].name, line);` and similarly with `printf("%s", (st+i)->index);` and `printf("%s", st[i].index);`.  You should also decide how to deal with newlines.  You're storing them at the moment.  That is usually not the best idea.  Using `line[strcspn(line, "\n"] = '\0';` is a neat and succinct way of zapping the newline if it is present.  You would then adjust your printing to include newlines at the appropriate points.

Comment: To debug your problem, you could add `printf("Read: [[%s]]\n", line);` after you zap the newline at the top of the loop, and then add `printf("Index: [[%s]]\n", st[i].index);` in the code block for `if (s5 == true)`, and similarly for the others too.  Basically, this checks that the program actually reads what you think it should be reading.  You can use any convenient marker character in place of the square brackets in the format strings; they help you identify oddball problems like CRLF (Windows/DOS-style line endings in the data).  Using `line[strcspn(line, "\n\r"] = '\0';` would fix CRLF.

Comment: Thanks for the structures — now can we have 10 or 15 lines of data?  Your structures won't store lines as big as you read with `fgets()`, and there is no overflow checking.  That could be a problem.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks! It was picking up the newline so using `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';` worked like a charm. As for the `kvizovi` --> `score` that is a translation issue that I missed out on, as I translated the code for easier readability. Also, I am sorry for not providing enough workable code, I didn't provide code that isn't directly related to my issue as I thought it would've been too irrelevant.

Comment: It is good to keep the code to a minimum, but it needs to be a MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  And it is now the input data that is missing.  Somewhere, you should keep a record of how many sets of student details were read so that you don't try to process more records.

Comment: Note well that the code we're asking for is not necessarily a collection of direct excerpts from the whole program.  You are expected to construct an example that reproduces the same issue, and it is often helpful to start from the whole program, but then follows a process of cutting out everything that is not essential to a working program that still manifests the issue.  When done right, the final result usually does not bear much resemblance to the original code.  This process is a powerful debugging technique in its own right, so it pays to learn and practice it.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is in the management of the 5 boolean variables.

#### Data

Here's a data file with 4 entries:

```
A-0123-21
John
Doe
83 | 49 | 78 | 79 | 88 | 34 | 45 | 77 | 40 | 61 | 55
----------------------------------------------
A-0124-52
William
Joyce
67 | 47 | 58 | 91 | 88 | 67 | 73 | 30 | 65 | 21 | 38
----------------------------------------------
A-2124-59
Susan
Winterbourne
30 | 80 | 31 | 50 | 29 | 28 | 94 | 36 | 58 | 82 | 65
----------------------------------------------
A-2374-63
Sally
Zacharias
42 | 67 | 59 | 57 | 92 | 41 | 77 | 59 | 77 | 50 | 86
----------------------------------------------
```

#### Minimally revised code

Here's a minimal adaptation of your code — primarily adding the newline handling and debug printing (source `io53.c`, program `io53`).  Note that you have 6 blocks of code to handle 5 different types of line; this is another part of your problems, I think.

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char index[10];
    char name[23];
    char surname[23];
    int scores[11];
} students;

typedef struct raw
{
    char score[70];
    char divider[70];
} data;

static int count;
static students st[120];
static data rw[120];

static void init_load(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[100];
    if ((fp = fopen("students.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    bool s1 = false, s2 = false, s3 = false, s4 = false, s5 = false;

    int id = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")] = '\0';
        printf("Read: [[%s]]\n", line);
        if (s5 == true)
        {
            s1 = false;
            s2 = false;
            s3 = false;
            s4 = false;
            s5 = false;
            strcpy(((st + id)->index), line);
            printf("[%d] index1  [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].index);
            s1 = true;
            id++;
        }
        else if (s4 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((rw + id)->divider), line);
            printf("[%d] divider [[%s]]\n", id, rw[id].divider);
            s5 = true;
        }
        else if (s3 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((rw + id)->score), line);
            printf("[%d] score   [[%s]]\n", id, rw[id].score);
            s4 = true;
        }
        else if (s2 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((st + id)->surname), line);
            printf("[%d] surname [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].surname);
            s3 = true;
        }
        else if (s1 == true)
        {
            strcpy(((st + id)->name), line);
            printf("[%d] name    [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].name);
            s2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("[%d] index2  [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].index);
            strcpy(((st + id)->index), line);
            s1 = true;
        }
    }
    count = id;
    fclose(fp);
}

static void print_students(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d].index   [[%s]]\n", i, (st + i)->index);
        printf("[%d].name    [[%s]]\n", i, (st + i)->name);
        printf("[%d].surname [[%s]]\n", i, (st + i)->surname);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    init_load();
    puts("\n");
    print_students();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Read: [[A-0123-21]]
[0] index2  [[]]
Read: [[John]]
[0] name    [[John]]
Read: [[Doe]]
[0] surname [[Doe]]
Read: [[83 | 49 | 78 | 79 | 88 | 34 | 45 | 77 | 40 | 61 | 55]]
[0] score   [[83 | 49 | 78 | 79 | 88 | 34 | 45 | 77 | 40 | 61 | 55]]
Read: [[----------------------------------------------]]
[0] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]
Read: [[A-0124-52]]
[0] index1  [[A-0124-52]]
Read: [[William]]
[1] name    [[William]]
Read: [[Joyce]]
[1] surname [[Joyce]]
Read: [[67 | 47 | 58 | 91 | 88 | 67 | 73 | 30 | 65 | 21 | 38]]
[1] score   [[67 | 47 | 58 | 91 | 88 | 67 | 73 | 30 | 65 | 21 | 38]]
Read: [[----------------------------------------------]]
[1] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]
Read: [[A-2124-59]]
[1] index1  [[A-2124-59]]
Read: [[Susan]]
[2] name    [[Susan]]
Read: [[Winterbourne]]
[2] surname [[Winterbourne]]
Read: [[30 | 80 | 31 | 50 | 29 | 28 | 94 | 36 | 58 | 82 | 65]]
[2] score   [[30 | 80 | 31 | 50 | 29 | 28 | 94 | 36 | 58 | 82 | 65]]
Read: [[----------------------------------------------]]
[2] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]
Read: [[A-2374-63]]
[2] index1  [[A-2374-63]]
Read: [[Sally]]
[3] name    [[Sally]]
Read: [[Zacharias]]
[3] surname [[Zacharias]]
Read: [[42 | 67 | 59 | 57 | 92 | 41 | 77 | 59 | 77 | 50 | 86]]
[3] score   [[42 | 67 | 59 | 57 | 92 | 41 | 77 | 59 | 77 | 50 | 86]]
Read: [[----------------------------------------------]]
[3] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]


[0].index   [[A-0124-52]]
[0].name    [[John]]
[0].surname [[Doe]]
[1].index   [[A-2124-59]]
[1].name    [[William]]
[1].surname [[Joyce]]
[2].index   [[A-2374-63]]
[2].name    [[Susan]]
[2].surname [[Winterbourne]]
```

Note that you didn't go through the `index1` code block again, so `id` did not get incremented, so effectively, the last student got left out of the printing, even though the data was read.

#### Revised code

I don't agree with using the five boolean variables; a simple counter would be much simpler to control.  This code (source `io97.c`, program `io97`) increments the `id` after processing a divider line, which is when a student's data is complete.  The `lineno` counter runs repeatedly from 0 to 4 because of the loop control — a `for` loop is remarkably flexible.  If the data file contains a partial student record, the partial record is effectively ignored.

Note that this does not check line lengths so buffer overflows are simple to create.  A student named "Henry Percival Alexander Williamsburg-Montgomery" would cause problems.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct student
{
    char index[10];
    char name[23];
    char surname[23];
    int scores[11];
} students;

typedef struct raw
{
    char score[70];
    char divider[70];
} data;

static int count;
static students st[120];
static data rw[120];

static void init_load(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[100];
    if ((fp = fopen("students.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int id = 0;
    for (int lineno = 0; fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL; lineno = (lineno + 1) % 5)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")] = '\0';
        printf("Read: (%d:%d) [[%s]]\n", id, lineno, line);
        if (lineno == 0)
        {
            strcpy(st[id].index, line);
            printf("[%d] index1  [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].index);
        }
        else if (lineno == 1)
        {
            strcpy(st[id].name, line);
            printf("[%d] name    [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].name);
        }
        else if (lineno == 2)
        {
            strcpy(st[id].surname, line);
            printf("[%d] surname [[%s]]\n", id, st[id].surname);
        }
        else if (lineno == 3)
        {
            strcpy(rw[id].score, line);
            printf("[%d] score   [[%s]]\n", id, rw[id].score);
        }
        else if (lineno == 4)
        {
            strcpy(rw[id].divider, line);
            printf("[%d] divider [[%s]]\n", id, rw[id].divider);
            id++;
        }
        else
        {
            abort();
        }
    }
    count = id;
    fclose(fp);
}

static void print_students(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d].index   [[%s]]\n", i, st[i].index);
        printf("[%d].name    [[%s]]\n", i, st[i].name);
        printf("[%d].surname [[%s]]\n", i, st[i].surname);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    init_load();
    puts("\n");
    print_students();
    return 0;
}
```

When run on the same data, it produces:

```
Read: (0:0) [[A-0123-21]]
[0] index1  [[A-0123-21]]
Read: (0:1) [[John]]
[0] name    [[John]]
Read: (0:2) [[Doe]]
[0] surname [[Doe]]
Read: (0:3) [[83 | 49 | 78 | 79 | 88 | 34 | 45 | 77 | 40 | 61 | 55]]
[0] score   [[83 | 49 | 78 | 79 | 88 | 34 | 45 | 77 | 40 | 61 | 55]]
Read: (0:4) [[----------------------------------------------]]
[0] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]
Read: (1:0) [[A-0124-52]]
[1] index1  [[A-0124-52]]
Read: (1:1) [[William]]
[1] name    [[William]]
Read: (1:2) [[Joyce]]
[1] surname [[Joyce]]
Read: (1:3) [[67 | 47 | 58 | 91 | 88 | 67 | 73 | 30 | 65 | 21 | 38]]
[1] score   [[67 | 47 | 58 | 91 | 88 | 67 | 73 | 30 | 65 | 21 | 38]]
Read: (1:4) [[----------------------------------------------]]
[1] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]
Read: (2:0) [[A-2124-59]]
[2] index1  [[A-2124-59]]
Read: (2:1) [[Susan]]
[2] name    [[Susan]]
Read: (2:2) [[Winterbourne]]
[2] surname [[Winterbourne]]
Read: (2:3) [[30 | 80 | 31 | 50 | 29 | 28 | 94 | 36 | 58 | 82 | 65]]
[2] score   [[30 | 80 | 31 | 50 | 29 | 28 | 94 | 36 | 58 | 82 | 65]]
Read: (2:4) [[----------------------------------------------]]
[2] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]
Read: (3:0) [[A-2374-63]]
[3] index1  [[A-2374-63]]
Read: (3:1) [[Sally]]
[3] name    [[Sally]]
Read: (3:2) [[Zacharias]]
[3] surname [[Zacharias]]
Read: (3:3) [[42 | 67 | 59 | 57 | 92 | 41 | 77 | 59 | 77 | 50 | 86]]
[3] score   [[42 | 67 | 59 | 57 | 92 | 41 | 77 | 59 | 77 | 50 | 86]]
Read: (3:4) [[----------------------------------------------]]
[3] divider [[----------------------------------------------]]


[0].index   [[A-0123-21]]
[0].name    [[John]]
[0].surname [[Doe]]
[1].index   [[A-0124-52]]
[1].name    [[William]]
[1].surname [[Joyce]]
[2].index   [[A-2124-59]]
[2].name    [[Susan]]
[2].surname [[Winterbourne]]
[3].index   [[A-2374-63]]
[3].name    [[Sally]]
[3].surname [[Zacharias]]
```